# How do I tell a python script to execute a particular python version in python script

Tags: python, pythonpath

My Jenkins is using python 2.7 to execute python scripts. But I want to execute the script using python 3.7. So far I have done something like this.

test.py

```
#!/home/sam/python/python3/bin/python3.8
import sys

print(sys.version)
```

I am executing this script with python test.py. In output I am getting python version 2.6.
Can anyone suggest how can I run the python script with python 3.7 path.

Comment: The shebang will only be honored if the script is launched like `test.py`, and NOT `python test.py`.  You need to use `python3 test.py` (or `/full/path/to/python3 test.py`).

Comment: Jenkins is launching the script like "python test.py".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select versions per command, you can use command line options like these:

```
py -2 my_file.py
py -3 my_file.py
py -2.7 my_file.py
py -3.4 my_file.py
```